# How to create records before load the form view on new record in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have the following models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    _name = 'discount_order.order'
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner','Cliente',required=True)
    order_lines_ids = fields.One2many('discount_order.order_line', 'order_id', string="Lineas")
    obs = fields.Text('Comentarios y observaciones')

class Order_line(models.Model):
    _name = 'discount_order.order_line'
    order_id = fields.Many2one('discount_order.order', string="Order")
    cat_id = fields.Many2one('product.category')
    disc_ask = fields.Float('Descuento solicitado')
    obs = fields.Char('Comentarios por linea')
```

I need to create 1 'order_line' for each 'product.category' record, when the user press the new button on the form view. So the new 'order object', already has assigned 'order_lines_ids'

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value of **order_lines_ids** of **discount_order.order** model.

Default value you can set from py as well as from xml file.
So when you create new record of model **discount_order.order** then order_lines_ids automatically set default values.